# Sencha on tab switch grid doesn't show

Tags: javascript, extjs, tabs, sencha-touch, tabpanel

I'm building a sencha app and when i remove a tab panel and switch to 1st tab i don't see the grid anymore. Then if i click on another tab and back the grid appears. It seems just that the setActiveItem() doesn't render the grid.

some code:

```
var tab = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#mainView')[0];
var nav = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#navBar')[0];

if(tab.getActiveItem().down('#allgrid')){
console.log('I think this tab should stay. Don\'t you?');
}
else{
var active = tab.getActiveItem();
tab.setActiveItem(0);
tab.remove(active,true);

}
```

Any help is appreciated. I tried refresh(), renderTo() and didn't get it right.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Sencha Touch OR Sencha Ext JS? Which version?

Comment: Sencha Touch 2.4.1 with grid 2.3.0